# HP service pack for Proliant with ESXi 5.0

Tags: hp, vmware-esx, hp-proliant, service-pack

Server: ProLiant DL380 G5
currently system ROM: P56 10/25/2010

I would like to upgrade the system service pack with HP Service Pack for Proliant 2014.06.0_784915-001
http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=1121413&swItemId=MTX_33222856ca304ee5807ac0de8a&swEnvOid=4115

This server is currently running Vmware ESXi5.0.0.

I would like to know how can I install the service pack remotely. I am unable to find full installation instructions unfortunately.

I have also been told, I can mount the ISO image from ILO and update the server. How do I so?

Comment: Do you have an iLO Advanced license for this system?

Comment: Sorry, we don't have advanced license. We have ILO 2 standard license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to activate iLO 2 Advance feature with trial key from HP. 
Mounted HP SPP iso to the virtual disk; rebooted server to update system.

Answer (score 0):

Find, buy or *pirate* an ILO2/3/4 key and it will unlock the features you need to perform a remote firmware DVD installation.

How far away is the server? You may be better off burning the DVD and shipping it to the server's location.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find a Trial Key for ilo 2 advanced on the internet:

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Integrity-Servers/ILO-2-trial-license-key/td-p/5546529#.VICAAjGG98E

There is: ilo 2 advanced pack - One-time trial, good for 30 days - 32RCX-GCG87-ZWBCX-NBD5C-6V9J7

But i can not confirm if this works. I only have newer ilo's. (3 or higher...)

If it does not work maybe you can find an official HP page for ilo2 adv. trial key... good luck!

EDIT:
also look at this: https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=ILO_TRIALS

Comment: Yes, I mananged to activate ILO 2 advanced with new evaluation key. How do I now install the updates via ILO ?

Comment: Hi Amir, i only can say how it would work for ilo 3. But try this out: log in ilo webpage, launch remote-console (java or .net), in the remote console there you must be able to connect in the .iso. In ilo3 its --> virtual drives --> ImageFile (CD-ROM/DVD) --> then select your .iso File and connect it. --> Then you have to reboot and start from CD/DVD. Then you can configure the Firmware Updates... hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to HP's documentation there is an online upgrade, if you have a windows/linux based OS you can run it from an online machine.

So my suggestion if you don't make ILO work, make a new virtual machine. Boot a version of ubuntu on it. And run the online installer from there. Unless you ofcause already have an active machine you would like to run it on.